# Диалоговое окно с выбором даты и времени

Tags: java, android

В приложении есть метод, который показывает диалоговое окно с выбором даты (DatePicker) и двумя кнопками Отмена и Принять.

Нужно чтобы после нажатия на кнопку Принять, выводилось ещё одно диалоговое окно, но уже с выбором времени (TimePicker) так же с двумя кнопками Отмена и Принять.

Сейчас реализовал только диалоговое окно с выбором даты.

Метод в активити, который показывает диалоговое окно:

```
private void setDateDeadline() {
    DateTimePickerDialog dialogDate = DateTimePickerDialog.newInstance(new DateTimePickerDialog.OnSetDateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void setDate(long date) {
            // помещаем выбранную дату в поле
            mDeadlineDate = date;
        }
    });
    dialogDate.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "DATE_DIALOG");
}
```

Класс диалогового окна с выбором даты:

```
public class DateTimePickerDialog extends DialogFragment implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
    private DatePicker mDatePiker;
    private OnSetDateCallback mCallback;

    interface OnSetDateCallback {
        void setDate(long date);
    }

    public static DateTimePickerDialog newInstance(OnSetDateCallback callback) {
        DateTimePickerDialog dialog = new DateTimePickerDialog();
        dialog.setDateCallback(callback);

        return dialog;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mDatePiker = new DatePicker(getActivity());

        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setView(mDatePiker)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.apply, this)
                .setNeutralButton(R.string.cancel, this);

        return adb.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        switch (which) {
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                int year = mDatePiker.getYear();
                int month = mDatePiker.getMonth();
                int day = mDatePiker.getDayOfMonth();

                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.set(year, month, day);

                // Возвращаем в активити выбранную дату
                mCallback.setDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
            break;
        }
    }

    private void setDateCallback(OnSetDateCallback callback) {
        mCallback = callback;
    }
}
```

**Подскажите, как реализовать показ модального окна с выбором времени, после того, как пользователь выбрал дату?**

Comment: можно не переходить на другой диалог, а просто подменять layout и все, два диалога как-то будет громоздко мне кажется)

Answer (score 1):

Странно, но после того как опубликовал вопрос, в голову пришла идея реализовать мою задумку вот так:

```
public class DateTimePickerDialog extends DialogFragment {
    private DatePicker mDatePiker;
    private TimePicker mTimePicker;
    private Calendar mCalendar;
    private OnSetDateCallback mCallback;

    interface OnSetDateCallback {
        void setDate(long date);
    }

    private DialogInterface.OnClickListener onClickPositiveButtonDateDialog = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            mCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, mDatePiker.getYear());
            mCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, mDatePiker.getMonth());
            mCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mDatePiker.getDayOfMonth());

            showTimePickerDialog();
        }
    };

    private DialogInterface.OnClickListener onClickPositiveButtonTimeDialog = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, mTimePicker.getHour());
            mCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mTimePicker.getMinute());

            mCallback.setDate(mCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
        }
    };

    public static DateTimePickerDialog newInstance(OnSetDateCallback callback) {
        DateTimePickerDialog dialog = new DateTimePickerDialog();
        dialog.setDateCallback(callback);

        return dialog;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        mDatePiker = new DatePicker(getActivity());
        mTimePicker = new TimePicker(getActivity());

        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setView(mDatePiker)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.apply, onClickPositiveButtonDateDialog)
                .setNeutralButton(R.string.cancel, null);

        return adb.create();
    }

    private void setDateCallback(OnSetDateCallback callback) {
        mCallback = callback;
    }

    private void showTimePickerDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        adb.setView(mTimePicker)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.apply, onClickPositiveButtonTimeDialog)
                .setNeutralButton(R.string.cancel, null);

        adb.show();
    }
}
```